# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in react if else statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to filter elements by their respective id via button click
first condition works fine when I click on it but when it has to check the `else if` conditions I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

HERES MY FUNCTION :

```
 filter(e){
        var filtertag = 'data-story-card';
        
        if (e.target.classList.contains(productive)) {
           filtertag = 'data-story-card-productive';
           document.getElementById('data-story-card-productive').style.display = "none"
           console.log(e.target.classList)
              
        }
        else if (e.target.classList.contains(inclusive)){
            filtertag = 'data-story-card-inclusive';
            document.getElementById('data-story-card-inclusive').style.display = "none"
            console.log(filtertag)
        }
        else if (e.target.classList.contains(well)) {
            filtertag = 'data-story-card-well-governed';
            document.getElementById('data-story-card-well-governed').style.display = "none"
            console.log(filtertag)
        }
        else if (e.target.classList.contains(sustainable)){
            filtertag = 'data-story-card-sustainable';
            document.getElementById('data-story-card-sustainable').style.display = "none"
            console.log(filtertag)
        }
        else if (e.target.classList.contains(built)){
            filtertag = 'data-story-card-built';
            document.getElementById('data-story-card-built').style.display = "none"
            console.log(filtertag)
        }
        else if (e.target.classList.contains(city)) {
            filtertag = 'data-story-card-city';
            document.getElementById('data-story-card-city').style.display = "none"
            console.log(filtertag)
        }

    }
```

Comment: If this is React, you should not be using DOM methods like `getElementById`, put that logic in the JSX instead

Comment: It's likely that this is not react, and that the code is being run before the DOM is ready. Which is why `document.getElementById` returns `null`.